# Error: page.evaluate: Target page, context or browser has been closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, playwright, browser-automation

I'm using playwright in my script. it's a simple workflow

1. page opens
2. enter in to while loop
3. do some some operations
4. wait for 26 minutes
5. click on modal ( this is where things going wrong)
6. go to the start of while loop

this is my code

```
while (true){
        try {
            let startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

            //click 2nd page button in pagination section
            const paginationButtonClicked = await page.evaluate(()=>{
                if(document.querySelectorAll('nav+div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) button:nth-child(3)')[0]){
                    document.querySelectorAll('nav+div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) button:nth-child(3)')[0].click()
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            console.log('paginationButtonClicked >> '+paginationButtonClicked);
            if(paginationButtonClicked || TOKEN){

                // auth token and x-api key should have captured by now
                if(TOKEN && APIKEY){
                    stock.run(TOKEN,APIKEY)
                }

            }
            else {
                await page.screenshot({'path':'no_pagination_button.jpeg'}).catch(e=>{
                    console.log('failed to get no_pagination_button ss');
                });
                
            }

            await sleep(60*26*1000)
            console.log('reload page after 26min '+new Date());

            //**** next step causing issues randomly ***//

            const refreshToken =await page.evaluate(()=>{

                if(document.querySelectorAll('wb-modal button')[3]){
                    document.querySelectorAll('wb-modal button')[3].click()
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }

            })

            console.log('refreshToken '+refreshToken);
            if(!refreshToken){

                await page.screenshot({'path':'no_refresh_token_button.jpeg'}).catch(e=>{
                    console.log('failed to get no_refresh_token_button ss');
                });
                
                await page.reload({waitUntil:"networkidle"})
            }


            //wait for page loads
            await sleep(60*1000)
            await page.screenshot({'path':'after_refresh_token_button_clicked.jpeg'}).catch(e=>{
                console.log('failed to get after_refresh_token_button_clicked ss');
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log('*** FALIURE IN WHILE LOOP ***');
            console.log(e);
            await sleep(60*1000)
        }

    }
```

log messages are printed until this line

`reload page after 26min`

after that this is the error message I get randomly

**FALIURE IN WHILE LOOP Error: page.evaluate: Target page, context or browser has been closed**

I have added `page.on('close', () => {console.log('page closed')})` code as well, but it does not return any message

there is no way to close the browser, since I haven't added browser.close() function in the code

my sleep function is something like this

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

what could be the reason for this random issue ?

is this because no page interaction for longer period ? (26 minutes)
or something else ?

Thanks